# How do I use Docker with GitHub Actions?

Tags: docker, github-actions

When I create a GitHub Actions workflow file, the example YAML file contains `runs-on: ubuntu-latest`. [According to the docs](https://help.github.com/en/articles/virtual-environments-for-github-actions#supported-virtual-environments), I only have the options between a couple versions of Ubuntu, Windows Server and macOS X.

I thought GitHub Actions runs inside Docker. How do I choose my Docker image?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A **job** (as part of a **workflow**) runs inside a virtual machine. You choose one of the environments [provided by them](https://help.github.com/en/articles/virtual-environments-for-github-actions#supported-virtual-environments) (e.g. `ubuntu-latest` or `windows-2019`).

A job consists of one or more **steps**. A step may be a simple shell command, using **run**. But it may also be an **action**, using **uses**

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04 # linux required if you want to use docker
    steps:
    # Those steps are executed directly on the VM
    - run: ls /
    - run: echo $HOME
    - name: Add a file
      run: touch $HOME/stuff.txt
    # Those steps are actions, which may run inside a container
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - uses: ./.github/actions/my-action
    - uses: docker://continuumio/anaconda3:2019.07
```

- `run: <COMMAND>` executes the command with the shell of the OS
- `uses: actions/checkout@v1` runs the action from the user / organization `actions` in the repository `checkout` (https://github.com/actions/checkout), major release 1
- `uses: ./.github/actions/my-action` runs the action which is defined in your own repository under this path
- `uses: docker://continuumio/anaconda3:2019.07` runs the `anaconda3` image from user / organization `continuumio`, version `2019.07`, from the Docker Hub (https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3)

Keep in mind that you [need to select a linux distribution](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-actions#types-of-actions) as the environment if you want to use Docker.

Take a look at the documentation for [uses](https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses) and [run](https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun) for further details.

It should also be noted that there is a `container` option, allowing you to run any steps that would usually run on the host to be runned inside a container: https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer

Comment: To your last point, I can't get my `run` commands to execute properly in the container, not even `echo "hello world"`. It just dies right after it was started, and then the job fails with `Error response from daemon: Container 60e7cf...0b17 is not running`. Do you know why that happens / how to fix it? The image I used was `python:3.7-alpine`.

Comment: @Arne No, not right away. Maybe just a bug on their side. But it's a bit out of scope of this question, I think you should open a new one and post your workflow.yml

Comment: Using the `docker://` scheme with `uses`, how can I specify run configurations?

Answer (score 121):

GitHub actions provision a virtual machine - as you noted, either Ubuntu, Windows or macOS - and run your workflow inside of that.  You *can* then use that virtual machine to run a workflow inside a container.

Use [the `container` specifier](https://help.github.com/en/github/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer) to run a step inside a container.  Be sure to specify `runs-on` as the appropriate host environment for your container (`ubuntu-latest` for Linux containers, `windows-latest` for Windows containers).  For example:

```
jobs:
  vm:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo This job does not specify a container.
          echo It runs directly on the virtual machine.
        name: Run on VM
  container:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: node:10.16-jessie
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo This job does specify a container.
          echo It runs in the container instead of the VM.
        name: Run in container
```

Comment: @FlorianWilhelm Author has corrected the syntax, works correctly now.

Comment: What if `container` is a private image in the GH registry? Will this still work?

Comment: Is there a way to cache the container image so that is not downloaded from docker hub every time a job is triggered?

Comment: Technically, it's the same job with 2 different actions.