# Missing installed dependencies when docker image is used

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, dockerfile, continuous-deployment, github-actions

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y install bzip2

RUN yarn global add @bluebase/cli && bluebase plugins:add @bluebase/cli-expo && bluebase plugins:add @bluebase/cli-web
RUN bluebase plugins
```

When the docker file is built it installs all dependencies, and the last command `RUN bluebase plugins` outputs the list of plugins installed. But when this image is pushed and used in github actions, `bluebase` is available globally but no plugins are installed. What am I doing wrong?

Github Workflow

```
name: Development CI

on:
  push:
    # Sequence of patterns matched against refs/heads
    branches:
      - '*' # Push events on all branchs
      - '*/*'
      - '!master' # Exclude master
      - '!next' # Exclude next
      - '!alpha' # Exclude alpha
      - '!beta' # Exclude beta

jobs:
web-deploy:
    container: 
      image: hashimsohail/bluebase-image
    name: Deploy Web
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Check BlueBase
        run: bluebase #Outputs list of comamnds available with bluebase

      - name: Check BlueBase Plugins
        run: bluebase plugins #Outputs no plugins installed
```

Comment: did not the run in your github overwrite the ones in the dockerfile ?

Comment: It can't overwrite, the first run command only checks if it's installed globally, the other should print the list of plugins installed, so I can move on further with the flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a tricky problem! Here is the solution that worked for me. I'll try and explain why below.

```
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    container:
      image: hashimsohail/bluebase-image
    name: Deploy Web
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Check BlueBase
        run: bluebase
      - name: Check BlueBase Plugins
        run: HOME=/root bluebase plugins
      - name: Check web plugin
        run: HOME=/root bluebase web:build --help
```

**Background**

Firstly the Docker image. The command `bluebase plugins:add` seems to be very dependent on the `$HOME` environment variable. Your Docker image is built as the `root` user, so `$HOME` is `/root`. The `bluebase plugins:add` command installs plugin dependencies at `$HOME/.cache/@bluebase` so they end up at `/root/.cache/@bluebase`.

Now the `jobs.<id>.container` feature. When your container is run there is some rather complicated Docker networking and volume mounts that take place. One of those mounts is `-v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home"`. This mounts local files from the host, including a copy of your checked out repository, into the container. Then it changes `$HOME` to point to `/github/home`.

**Problem**

The reason `bluebase plugins` doesn't work is because it depends on `$HOME` pointing to `/root` but now GitHub Actions has changed it to `/github/home`.

**Solutions**

A solution I tried was to install the plugins at `/github/home` instead of `/root` in the Docker image.

```
FROM node:10

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y install bzip2

RUN mkdir -p /github/home
ENV HOME /github/home

RUN yarn global add @bluebase/cli && bluebase plugins:add @bluebase/cli-expo && bluebase plugins:add @bluebase/cli-web
RUN bluebase plugins
```

The problem with this is that the volume mount that GitHub Actions creates overwrites the `/github/home` directory. So then I tried a few tricks like symlinks or moving the `.cache/@bluebase` directory around to avoid it being clobbered by the mount. None of those worked.

So the only solution seemed to be changing `$HOME` back to `/root`. This should *NOT* be done permanently in the workflow because GitHub Actions depends on `HOME=/github/home` to work correctly. So the solution is to set it temporarily for each command.

```
HOME=/root bluebase web:build --help
```

**Takeaway**

The main takeaway from this is that any tooling pre-built in a container that relies on `$HOME` pointing to a specific location may not work correctly when used in the `jobs.<container_id>.container` syntax.

Comment: Can you help me with increasing watchers in this docker image? 
I'm getting this error `sysctl: setting key "fs.inotify.max_user_watches": Read-only file system
`

Comment: I don't know anything about doing that I'm afraid. It's probably best to make a new question because it's not the same problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the issue with the image, it's easy to confirm on local image and you will see the that the plugin is available in Docker image.

Just try to run

```
docker build -t plugintest .
#then run the image on local system to verify plugin
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint "/bin/sh" plugintest -c "bluebase plugins"
```

Seems like the issue with your YML config file.

```
      image: hashimsohail/bluebase-image
    name: Deploy Web
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

This line `runs-on: ubuntu-latest` make does not sense, I think it should be
`runs-on:ashimsohail/bluebase-image`.

Comment: There is only a limited list of options for runs-on

For the reference official documentation
https://help.github.com/en/github/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idruns-on

Comment: Did you confirm the plugin as I mentioned to test?

Comment: Though the output of `docker run -it --rm --entrypoint "/bin/sh" plugintest -c "bluebase plugins"` shows list of plugins

Comment: Yes the list is printed when I run the image locally

Comment: So  this is confirmed that the issue with your github yml configuration, not the issue with docker image.

Comment: What can be a workaround? I'm tired of installing all the clis/plugins again and again in every github workflow.

Comment: I did not work github action, but you anc check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549439/how-do-i-use-docker-with-github-actions