# How to use docker images when building artefacts in Actions?

Tags: docker, github-actions

**TL;DR:** I would like to use on a self-hosted Actions runner (itself a docker container on my docker engine) specific docker images to build artefacts that I would move between the build phases, and end with a standalone executable (not a docker container to be deployed). I do not know how to use docker containers as "building engines" in Actions.

**Details**: I have a home project consisting of a backend in Go (cross compiled to a standalone binary) and a frontend in Javascript (actually a framework: Quasar).

I develop on my laptop in Windows and use GitHub as the SCM.

The manual steps I do are:

- build a static version of the frontend which lands in a directory `spa`
- copy that directory to the backend directory
- compile the executable that embeds the `spa` directory
- copy (`scp`) this executable to the final destination

For development purposes this works fine.

I now would like to use Actions to automate the whole thing. I use docker based self-hosted runners (`tcardonne/github-runner`).

**My problem**: the containers do a great job isolating the build environment from the server they run on. They are however reused across build jobs and this may create conflicts. More importantly, the default versions of software provided by these containers is not the right (usually - latest) one.

The solution would be to run the build phases in disposable docker containers (that would base on the right image, shortening the build time as a collateral nice to have). Unfortunately, I do not know how to set this up.

Note: I do not want to ultimately create docker containers, I just want to use them as "building engines" and extract the artefacts from them, and share between the jobs (in my specific case - one job would be to build the front with quasar and generate a directory, the other one would be a compilation ending up with a standalone executable copied elsewhere)

Comment: Azure (`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software`) or Github (`https://docs.github.com/es/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#preinstalled-software`) agents include plenty of updated software. As you to wish to run a self-hosted, you need to build an agent including software you will need. This process is a bit tricky IMHO. Instructions here (`https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/docs/create-image-and-azure-resources.md`).

Comment: `... They are however reused across build jobs ...` From `https://docs.github.com/es/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#about-github-hosted-runners`. The same container is used between steps, not jobs. `Each job in a workflow executes in a fresh instance of the virtual machine. All steps in the job execute in the same instance of the virtual machine, allowing the actions in that job to share information using the filesystem`

Comment: @usuario: yes, the **github** runners are recreated every time. Not the self-hosted ones.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting premise, you can certainly do this!

I think you may be slightly mistaken with regards to:

> They are however reused across build jobs and this may create conflicts

If you run a new container from an image, then you will start with a fresh instance of that container. Files, software, etc, all adhering to the original image definition. Which is good, as this certainly aids your efforts. Let me know if I have the wrong end of the stick in regards to the above though.

### Base Image

You can define your own image for building, in order to mitigate shortfalls of public images that may not be up to date, or suit your requirements. In fact, this is a common pattern for CI, and Google does something similar with their [cloud build configuration](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers). For either approach below, you will likely want to do something like the following to ensure you have all the build tools you may

As a rough example:

```
FROM golang:1.16.7-buster

RUN apt update && apt install -y \
    git \
    make \
    ...
    && useradd <myuser> \
    && mkdir /dist

USER myuser
```

You could build and publish this with the following tag:

```
docker build . -t <containerregistry>:buildr/golang
```

It would also be recommended that you maintain a separate builder image for other types of projects, such as node, python, etc.

### Approaches

#### Building with layers

If you're looking to leverage build caching for your applications, this will be the better option for you. Caching is only effective if nothing has changed, and since the projects will be built in isolation, it makes it relatively safe.

Building your app may look something like the following:

```
FROM <containerregistry>:buildr/golang as builder

COPY src/ .

RUN make dependencies
RUN make
RUN mv /path/to/compiled/app /dist

FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /dist /dist
```

The gist of this is that you would start building your app within the builder image, such that it includes all the build deps you require, and then use a multi stage file to publish a final static container that includes your compiled source code, with no dependencies (using the [scratch image](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch) as the smallest image possible ).

Getting the final files out of your image would be a bit harder using this approach, as you would have to run an instance of the container once published in order to mount the files and persist it to disk, or use `docker cp` to retrieve the files from a running container (not image) to your disk.

In Github actions, this would look like running a step that builds a Docker container, where the step can occur anywhere with `docker` accessibility

[For example](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-and-push-docker-images):

```
jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
       ...
      - name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: user/app:latest
```

### Building as a process

This one can not leverage build caching as well, but you may be able to do clever things like mounting a host npm cache into your container to aid in actions like `npm restore`.

This approach differs from the former in that the way you build your app will be defined via CI / a purposeful script, as opposed to the Dockerfile.

In this scenario, it would make more sense to define the CMD in the parent image, and mount your source code in, thus not maintaining a image *per project* you are building.

This would shift the responsibility of building your application from the *buildtime of the image, to the runtime*. Retrieving your code from the container would be doable  through volume mounting for example:

```
docker run -v /path/to/src:/src /path/to/dist:/dist <containerregistry>:buildr/golang
```

If the `CMD` was defined in the builder, that single script would execute and build the mounted in source code, and subsequently publish to `/dist` in the container, which would then be persisted to your host via that volume mapping.

Of course, this applies if you're building locally. It actually becomes a bit nicer in a Github actions context if you wish to keep your build instructions there. You can choose to run steps within your builder container using something like the [following suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549439/how-do-i-use-docker-with-github-actions)

```
jobs:
  ...
  container:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: <containerregistry>:buildr/golang
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo This job does specify a container.
          echo It runs in the container instead of the VM.
        name: Run in container
```

Within that `run:` spec, you could choose to call a build script, or enter the commands that might be present in the script yourself.

What you do with the compiled source is muchly up to you once acquired

### Chaining (Frontend / Backend)

You mentioned that you build static assets for your site and then embed them into your golang binary to be served.

Something like that introduces complications of course, but nothing untoward. If you do not need to retrieve your web files until you build your golang container, then you may consider taking the first approach, and copying the content from the published image as part of a Docker directive. This makes more sense if you have two separate projects, one for frontend and backend.

If everything is in one folder, then it sounds like you may just want to extend your build image to facilitate `go` and `js`, and then take the latter approach and define those build instructions in a script, makefile, or your `run:` config in your actions file

### Conclusion

This is alot of info, I hope it's digestible for you, and more importantly, I hope it gives you some ideas as to how you can tackle your current issue. Let me know if you would like clarity in the comments

Comment: *I think you may be slightly mistaken with regards to* : the docker image **of the runner** runs continuously - it is not updated between builds.

Comment: Thanks for the general information - I use docker extensively (at my limited level) and it is not the building (layers, Docerfile, etc.) that is a problem, but rather the docker-in-docker build.

Comment: Ah I see, I did think I might have misread that initial part. While the runner is up 24/7, the building happens in another container (The runner usually has access to the docker socket on the host). As noted in `Building as a process`, specifying the container to run the step in will make your runner container launch a new image which the commands will be executed in. So the build environment will not be reused