# Can a single repo contain 2 or more actions.yml?

Tags: github-actions

I'm reading [this quickstart guide](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action).

The guide provides an example `actions.yml`:

```
# action.yml
name: 'Hello World'
description: 'Greet someone and record the time'
inputs:
  who-to-greet:  # id of input
    description: 'Who to greet'
    required: true
    default: 'World'
outputs:
  time: # id of output
    description: 'The time we greeted you'
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'
  args:
    - ${{ inputs.who-to-greet }}
```

My question concerns the last section in this file, `runs:`. My workflow will use multiple docker images. What's the 'right' way to do this? Should I create multiple `actions.yml`? Should I use multiple repos? Or can I somehow reference multiple `Dockerfile`'s within `runs:`?

Comment: What do you mean by "My workflow will use multiple docker images"? Multiple image references in your `Dockerfile`? Please tell what exactly you wanted to achieve to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Hi @LexLi I mean that I have one repo that is intended to work as a pipeline Within this repo are two Dockerfiles, one for snowsql and one for r. The snowsql docker image should get data from snowflake. Then the r image should process that data. In the tutorial I linked to the example uses a single Dockerfile within a repo `runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'`. My question is, can I use multiple Dockerfiles? If so, how/what's the syntax, as opposed to `runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'`?

Comment: First check if multi-stage builds is what you can utilize, https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds If so, you only need a single `Dockerfile` and all other questions are no longer needed.

Comment: This may be a work around but it does not answer my question :)

Comment: There are quite a few question marks above, so not sure what is your "question" to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs only mention the [usage of a single docker image](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runs-for-docker-actions) in a docker action.

It is however possible to run docker containers in a step of a normal workflow [as stated in this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57549440/5798347). This means you can create a [composite action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-run-steps-action) to make use of the same features provided by a normal workflow.

```
name: CI
on: [push]
jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest # linux required if you want to use docker
    steps:
    - uses: docker://continuumio/anaconda3:2019.07 # runs anaconda image from DockerHub
```